# The Long Bus Ride

Tags: lateral-thinking, story

I expect multiple answers to this, however only 1 of them is correct.

A bus was scheduled to stop 10 times today. Each time, 7 people got on the bus and 5 got off.

At the last stop, how many people were in the bus before the driver kicked them off?

Comment: On another note to my previous comment, if a riddle can have multiple answers (and you expect them) it's probably not precise enough. It should be possible to say for definite "this is my answer, and I know it's right"

Comment: I understand that. My explanation will explain and it WILL be right.

Comment: I could make a pretty decent case for the answer being 19, 20, 21, 24, 25 or 26. I could be missing the trap, but the point is that depending on things you don't specify (like when the count is taken, whether "getting off" is the same as being "kicked off", etc) leave it so open-ended that it feels like the right answer is arbitrarily right because that's just the one you want to see

Comment: None of those are correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a few answers I feel are justifiable, given the question in its present state. If you want any specific number explaining a bit more, feel free to ask.

**1 person**: The question states that people get "on" and "off" the bus, but none get "in", so the driver is the only one "in" the bus, the passengers are all sat on the roof.

This is apparently the correct answer. Or the one the OP wanted to see, anyway.

---

**26 people**: (+7 -5) * 9 = 18 + 7 = 25. The driver is the 26th. The 5 who would have got off get kicked off instead.

**25 people**: (+7 -5) * 9 = 18 + 7 = 25. Since the driver is **kicking people off** he doesn't count (you wouldn't kick yourself off a bus). The 5 who would have got off get kicked off instead.

**24 people**: Same logic as above, except the driver is one of the first 7 people getting on, and doesn't kick himself off.

**21 people**: (+7 -5) * 10 = 20. The driver is the 21st.

**20 people**: (+7 -5) * 10 = 20. Since the driver is **kicking people off** he doesn't count (you wouldn't kick yourself off a bus).

**19 people**: (+7 -5) * 9 = 18. The driver is the 19th. It's the final stop, end of the line, nobody can get on, everyone left is kicked off.

**18 people**: (+7 -5) * 9 = 18. It's the final stop, end of the line, nobody can get on, everyone left is kicked off. Since the driver is **kicking people off** he doesn't count (you wouldn't kick yourself off a bus).

**17 people**: Same logic as above, except the driver is one of the first 7 people getting on, and doesn't kick himself off.

**Trick question**: You didn't say the driver actually kicks anyone off (so he doesn't kick anyone off), you just asked how many were on the bus before he kicked them off.

Comment: None of them are correct. The answer is actually quite simple. Think outside the box

Comment: @warspyking OK, I'll literally think outside the box (and I mean literally :P). You state that every stop, people get **on** and **off**, but nobody gets **in**, so the driver is the only one in the bus. Everyone else is sat on the roof :-)

Comment: Joe your right! Post that as an answer so I can accept it

Comment: OK. I'm going to delete my answers now.

Comment: @warspyking I've edited it in, but it just doesn't sit right with me. I get that riddles are meant to debunk things you assume to be correct and think laterally, but getting "on the bus" or "on the train" are so idiomatic that it really feels more like a nitpick than a riddle. Yes, **technically** you can argue it, but it just doesn't feel very riddle-y to me

Comment: In followup to my previous comment, I think that things like this are more legitimate when the rest of the riddle is designed to be bulletproof. "At the last stop" is quite non-specific as to whether it's before or after the get on/off process, and there was nothing saying the driver would kick people off at the end of the day, calling into question whether or not he actually does that (since the direct question part can't be trusted to not be a trick)

Comment: Well I designed the riddle to get people thinking of possible answers, or solutions, when in reality, the real, and all too simple, answer was right under their noses.

Comment: That's fine, I just don't see anything inherently wrong with ... any of the other possible answers either I or @JoelRondeau gave. Hover over the `brainteaser` tag and re-read the description :-)

Comment: Oops. Lol that didn't work...

Comment: The problem does not specify that the driver is in the bus.  That's because the driver is outside the bus, and is using a remote control.  The correct answer is zero.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably the wrong answer, but here goes:
It's a trick question. You never say how many people are on the bus at the start, so it could virtually be any number. For all we know, there could be 300 at the last stop! (although that would be **quite** a packed bus)

Comment: See the accepted answer.

Comment: Okay. I just wanted to post that as an alternate answer. Cool puzzle, though!